# Using jar within gwt

Tags: java, gwt, jar

A quick and simple question:).

I have a .jar with allot of classes and I want to use them both in the Client (GWT) and server side.

If I add the .jar to the web server lib folder GWT compiler can't reach it. And putting on the .shared folder also doesn't work.

So what can I do to have access to the classes within the .jar container both in the server side and Java google web toolkit Client Code?

PS: I obviously don't want to take out all the classes from the .jar container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK in this case (shared classes) source must be compiled by GWT so you cannot just drop any .jar with precompiled classes. If you don't want to unpack classes for example to separate project (for those source classes) and include to main project, you can include the source files in .jar. In either way you need source classes.

Comment: What should I do exactly? How can I compile the .jar container with GWT and make the source classes within the .jar available for the GWT client?

Comment: this should help with referencing modules http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=229

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should keep in mind. Your jar should contain code which is able to compile by gwt compiler. Because If u want to make as shared so it should be compatible with server and client both. Same server could not understand client code vice versa.it works just put jar in to library path or make project dependedency.